# how to convert a form in mvc to ajaxform

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I possibly convert the following into Ajaxform.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Survey", "Tools", new { QuestionId = Model.QuestionId }, FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return getCheckedRadioButton();" }))
{
//  some processing
   <input type="submit" value="Next" id="submitButton" />
}
```

I have tried different parameters with Ajax.BeginForm but keep getting errors

Comment: Here is a similar overload for ajax.beginform, is there something specific you're having an issue with?http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505013(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Please give code what you tried for `Ajax.Beginform`

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionMethod", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", OnFailure = "OnFailure" }))
{

 // your stuff

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do any Ajax function in mvc project you should include following two js files:

```
jQuery (~/Scripts/jquery-{latest}.js)
```

and the MVC plugin for unobtrusive Ajax with

```
jQuery (~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js).
```

And 
 Enable Ajax option in Web.config file

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionMethod", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", OnFailure = "OnFailure" }))
{
<input type="submit" value="Next" id="submitButton" />
}
```